# How to sync my Facebook contacts?

Tags: contacts, sync, facebook, samsung-galaxy-spica

How do I sync my Facebook contacts with the contacts on my Samsung Galaxy Spica?

Comment: Is there a way to choose which of my facebook contacts I want synced?

Comment: @Slavo, you should probably make that a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Settings >> Accounts and Sync >> Add account >> Facebook
2. Enter your facebook info
3. Check the Sync Contacts checkbox

Comment: Your phone has to have the official Facebook app (or perhaps some 3rd-party app supports this too, not sure) installed.

Comment: I have the official app and it's not syncing!!!

Comment: I had spica back then and it was not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SyncMyPix](http://code.google.com/p/syncmypix/) to download display pictures off Facebook of your contacts and use those for pre-existing contacts.