# How can I choose which contacts to sync from Facebook to my HTC Desire HD?

Tags: contacts, sync, facebook, htc-desire-hd

In relation to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1838/how-to-sync-my-facebook-contacts), I asked if there is a way to choose which contacts get synced and got a suggestion to post this as a new question.

So here it is. How can I manually choose which Facebook contacts should be synced with my Android ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Facebook app doesn't have an option for it, so basically: You can't.  Facebook also provides no way to easily export contact information, so you'd have to do it manually (or with some crazy script/app that scrapes the info from the website).

Answer (score 2):

Download [Facebook Contact Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ro.weednet.contactssync&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDMsInJvLndlZWRuZXQuY29udGFjdHNzeW5jIl0.). I had this same problem and found this tool. Its not foolproof as the name in your contacts has to pretty much exactly match what they have in FB as their name. So people using weird names so they can't be found will not allow them to sync. Otherwise it works well.